# container class in bootstrap always focuses on the first columns on the left when resizing the browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The container class in bootstrap always focuses on the first columns on the left `class="col-lg-3"` when resizing the browser. How can it focus on the middle column `col-lg-6` instead ?

Before resizing :

[image]

After resizing :

[image]

First part of Bootstrap code :

```
   <section class="newsfeed">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">

     <a href="#">
     <div class="storybox" 
       style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(34,34,34,0.78), rgba(34,34,34,0.78)), url('assets/img/posts/2.gif') no-repeat;
              background-size: cover;
                  background-position: center center;
                  -webkit-background-size: cover;
                  -moz-background-size: cover;
                  -o-background-size: cover;">
          <div class="story-body text-center">
           <div class=""><img class="img-circle" src="assets/img/users/10.jpg" alt="user"></div>
           <h4>Clifford Graham</h4>
           <p>2 hours ago</p>
          </div>      
     </div>
     </a>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. By "focus the middle column" do you mean you're wanting the middle column contents to be top of the viewport? Or something else?

Comment: yes, this is what I need

Comment: You'll need javascript for that.

Comment: Post *all* of the code please.  I only see `col-lg-3` and several unclosed divs

Answer (score 0):

Use the flex-box order utilities built into Bootstrap to adjust the order of content:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order

By adding the order-first class to a column container ( in your example add it to col-lg-6 )  it will be moved first in the order. You can then use order-md-0, order-lg-0, or order-xl-0 to the same container to move it back to the normal flow of content depending on the device size you need.

The order-first utility class works by setting the CSS property order to -1, order-0 will reset the order property to it's default value of 0 to return it to the normal flow of content.